# Проблема с сокетами в *nix

Tags: c, многопоточность, сокет, c++, linux

Сервер пишется на C, делает по потоку на каждое соединение.
Приведу пример проблемы:

1. Начинаю слушать порт, в ожидании новых подключений;
2. Ко мне подключился клиент1 (файловый дескриптор сокета = 3) и присылает данные для обработки;
3. Пока сервер пыхтит над данными, клиент по какой-то причине отключается;
4. Подключается другой клиент2 (у него файловый дескриптор сокета тоже оказывается = 3!!);
5. Сервер закончил обработку данных и начинает писать в файловый дескриптор сокета = 3, т.е, он думает что данные ушли клиенту1, а на самом деле клиенту2, который затем благополучной упал и дальше мясо...

Вообщем, проблема в том что если соединение разрывается (-1), то следующий подключившийся получит сокет с тем же файловым дескриптором(+1)...как с этим бороться?

Как вариант конечно можно для каждого соединения порождать не поток а процесс и тогда их файловые дескрипторы не пересекутся, но все-таки не уж-то нельзя это как-то обойти с потоками?

Да, именно TCP.

P.S. подобная ситуация возникает даже при общении с обычными файлами, вот простой пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    FILE * f = fopen("tmp.txt", "w");
    printf("descriptor1 = %d\n", fileno(f));
    fprintf(f, "some text");
    fclose(f);

    f = fopen("tmp.txt", "r");
    printf("descriptor2 = %d\n", fileno(f));
    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

> descriptor1 = 3
>
> descriptor2 = 3

Проблема в том, ядро после закрытия файлового дескриптора, уменьшает максимальный файловый дескриптор для процесса (разумеется если закрываем последний открытый), а при открытии возвращает максимальный + 1...как от этого избавиться в рамках одного процесса ума не приложу...

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас TCP? А вы уверены, что шлёте туда куда надо и дескриптор берёте тот, что должен быть? По вашим симптомам вы точно что-то напутали.

Comment: "Вообщем, проблема в том что если соединение разрывается (-1), то следующий подключившийся получит сокет с тем же файловым дескриптором(+1)...как с этим бороться?" - такое не может быть. Если клиент закрывает сокет, то закрывается он только на его конце.. а на вашем он сам не закроется.. так что этот номер никем не может быть занят, пока вы сами не освободите его. Пример с файлами не валиден: вы закрыли первый файл сами. Так что вы делаете что-то не то и делаете неверные выводы. Если бы такое могло быть, то это был бы epic fail.

Comment: Дайте исходный код сервера.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Из Вашего примера можно сделать вывод, что Вы пытаетесь работать с клиентом по тому же сокету, который используете в accept().

Для общения с клиентом надо использовать сокет, возвращаемый accept(). См. man 2 accept